# Where does Telegram save sent pictures?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, bq, telegram

When someone sends me a picture, where does Telegram save it on the storage? Is there a special folder? Or do I have to save every single picture manually and even if I press "save" to gallaery, where does it save it on the storage then?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are saved in `/home/phablet/.cache/com.ubuntu.telegram/"your-phone-number"/photos`
this is a hidden folder, so you will have to activate show hidden files in the file manager.

If you save to gallery they are saved under `/home/phablet/pictures`

Comment: Okay, thank you! Saving to the gallery and finding it in "pictures" works, but I really can't find that ".cache" folder.. how is that possible?

Comment: Oh okay, I found it in the file manager on the phone!  Is it also possible to show the folder on the desktop PC? I can't find it there.

Comment: Is it also possible to show the folder on the desktop PC? I can't find it there.  On the phone I have to type in the password to show hidden folders, but on the PC i don't see hidden folders.

Comment: This is not possible by means of MTP, as these directories are not accessible over MTP (the protocol used when you connect via USB). I think it is possible over ssh, but can't try that at the moment. If this answer helped/solved your problem, consider accepting it as the answer.